# SQL Server Report Builder Page Details Format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report done in MS Access 2010 which when opened displays data which is grouped into two groups (items of type A and items of type B).

The items of type B is exponentially more than the items of type A and when you Print Preview the report, I have made it so that it only shows a total of items of type B but the full list of items of type A (in the VBA code of the Details_Format I simply prevented the items of type B being displayed).

This report has been moved over to SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services, but can I get the same formatting behaviour as on Access (hiding the detail on items of type B)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're displaying rows in a table and just want to hide rows of a certain type, set the visibility of the row to something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "B", true, false)
```

**Edit after comment:**

I see you're already accepted the answer (thanks!) but something else that might be useful is the `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` report variable. In the comment you note you're using Report Builder 3.0 (SSRS 2008R2) so this is possible.

See details under [Render Format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can hide objects based on the render format, so in your case you might want to only show Type B rows when exporting to PDF, so you could use a row visibility expression like:

```
=IIf(Globals.RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", false, true)
```

This will only show the object when it's rendered as PDF. You won't see the rows online in Report Manager (i.e. HTML).

Comment: Is there no 'softcopy' view and 'hardcopy' view on report builder 3? Similar to Access' Report View and Print Preview?

Comment: You can achieve similar functionality; please see extra details added to answer.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I'll play with that. I take it then that you can 'reverse' it as well, by having it display on HTML and not when printing. Would that be possible?